# how to find dates that overlap from two different dataframes and subset

Tags: r, date, dplyr

I would like to use a date from dataframe A to find any dates within 180 days of this date to select rows in dataframe B, with matching ID's.

eg.

```
Dataframe A
ID  Date A
42  2012-07-21
42  2013-04-12
167 2009-04-27
167 2010-04-19
105 2010-12-16
105 2012-01-05


Dataframe B
ID Date B
12 2016-09-08
35 2008-02-02
42 2012-01-09
42 2013-03-13
167 2010-08-02
105 2010-11-26
105 2011-08-12
105 2011-11-11
105 2013-03-15
105 2013-09-13
```

I would like to create a dataframe that provides the closest combination of dates as well as ensuring that there are a minimum of 3 Date B's in the sequence. So date A is the reference date, and the first date B needs to be within 180+/- of date A, as well as have at least two subsequent dates. 
If there are two ore more potential date A and B combinations, I would pick the combination that preserves a minimum of 3 date Bs as the preference.

```
ID  Date A        Date B
105 2012-01-05    2011-11-11
105 2012-01-05    2013-03-15
105 2012-01-05    2013-09-13
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a big data, I would suggest using data.tables *rolling join* instead

Assuming these are your data sets

```
dfa <- read.table(text = "ID  Date
                  42  '2012-07-21'
                  42  '2013-04-12'", header = TRUE)

dfb <- read.table(text = "ID Date
                  12 '2016-09-08'
                  35 '2008-02-02'
                  42 '2012-01-09'
                  42 '2013-03-13'", header = TRUE)
```

We will convert them to data.tables and convert the `Date` column to `IDate` class

```
library(data.table) #1.9.8+
setDT(dfa)[, Date := as.IDate(Date)]
setDT(dfb)[, Date := as.IDate(Date)]
```

Then, simply join away (you can do the rolling join both ways)

```
# You can perform another rolling join for `roll = -180` too
indx <- dfb[
            dfa, # Per each row in dfa find a match in dfb
            on = .(ID, Date), # The columns to join by
            roll = 180, # Rolling window, can join again on -180 afterwards
            which = TRUE, # Return the row index within `dfb` that been matched
            mult = "first", # Multiple match handling- take only the first match
            nomatch = 0L # Don't return unmatched indexes (NAs)
           ]

dfb[indx]
#    ID       Date
# 1: 42 2013-03-13
```

---

An alternative way achieving this, is to use data.tables *non-equi* join feature on *Date +-180* (manually created) columns

```
# Create range columns
dfa[, c("Date_m_180", "Date_p_180") := .(Date - 180L, Date + 180L)]

# Join away
indx <- dfb[dfa, 
            on = .(ID, Date >= Date_m_180, Date <= Date_p_180), 
            which = TRUE, 
            mult = "first",
            nomatch = 0L]
dfb[indx]
#    ID       Date
# 1: 42 2013-03-13
```

Both methods should handle large data sets almost instantly

Comment: Many thanks. I have tried the first option and it seems to work. The only issue is that dataframe B is very large and each ID can have numerous dates that may fall within the +/-180 days of Date A. I would like to select the date B that is the closest to Date A.

Comment: A minor thing - how can I revert back to a dataframe from the indx data table? Ie. I would like to subset the the dataframe B

Comment: I don't understand the question. Yo can save the result as follows `dfc <- dfb[indx]`. If you want to convert it back to a normal dataframe, use `setDF(dfc)`

Comment: thank you. Is there a way to select the date B that is the closest to Date A if there are multiple within the +/-180 days?

Comment: It is doing it by default. If you have multiple in `dfb` that fall in the ranges of multiple ranges in `dfa` and you want only the first, add `, mult = "first"` to the join.

Comment: The second method returns several dates from dataframe B for each ID. I want just one date for each ID that is the closest to Date A and within 180days

Comment: I've made an edit with some explanations of the code

Comment: To add some complexity - I've just realised that in dataframe A, each ID can have several dates. So if there is no match in dataframe B, I would need to select the next date A to match with. ie. in the end I should have only one date from dataframe B. This is why I started with a loop to code this, as it needs to loop back to the next Date A for each ID, if a match isn't found. ... Sorry if this isn't clear

Comment: You can do another join with `roll = "nearest"` on the unmatched dates. But this is hard to check without a full example with different scenarios. The example you've provided in the question is too simplistic.

Comment: Hi, I have provided more data and edited my question. I have realised that what I need it is actually quite a bit more complex than my first question posed.

Comment: Hi david, your second solution works fine, only I need to find the date B that is the closest to date A out of the multiples. Using mult=first I only get the first of the multiples within that timeframe.